# max element from list after adding a new element and removing the oldest

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of integers with a maximum element and I need to keep track of the maximum element in the list:

```
[3, 1, 2] (3 is the max)
```

Every time period, I get a new random element, add it to the end of the list, and remove the first element of the list in constant time. So, at the end of the current time period, my list will transform like this:

```
    [3, 1, 2]      (3 is the max)
->  [3, 1, 2, -5]  (don't care about max at this moment)
->  [1, 2, -5]     (now 2 is the max)
```

I could keep a priority queue keyed on the values in the list, giving O(log(n)) insertion and deletion, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient (possibly [amortized] constant time?) way to do it.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could do better than `O(log(n))`

Comment: Maybe try posting this on http://cs.stackexchange.com/?  Even if an O(1) algorithm is impossible, I'd be interested in a proof that such an algorithm is impossible.  Maybe a reduction argument showing that if you had such a method, you could implement sort in O(N) or something.

Comment: You could use something like ArrayList in Java to keep track of the number of occurrences of each value (which is what Pieter Geerkens suggests in his answer); this has the ugly downside that that'll take you O(k) space though where k is the maximum of the absolute values of the elements of your list. You could keep that smaller by using a hashing structure for keeping count, which will cost you O(n) space and an amortized (!) O(1) time for the occurrence counter.

Comment: On the other hand, the number of occurrences of any one element in the queue doesn't really help with anything; when the last occurrence of the maximum element is deleted, you'll still have to search for the new maximum.

Comment: @torquestomp: That's exactly the case. If you have a data structure into which you can insert and remove items in less than log(n) (combined time), then you could sort faster than n log n. We already know that doing so is impossible. Some heap variants allow O(1) insertion, but removing is always log(n) (sometimes amortized).

Comment: @Jim Mischel: That's not quite what I was getting at.  The lack of an O(1) maintainable sorted structure just shows that the algorithm described below by Pieter can't possibly be O(1) in general.  What I'm interested in is proof by contradiction:  Namely that, if we suppose that some black box list structure exists that can push-pop-getMax() in O(1) time, and we can construct an algorithm around this black box that lets us sort a list of generic data in O(N) time, we will have proved that such a black box list structure cannot exist.

Comment: @torquestomp: While my algorithm cannot be O(1) "in general", it may be for many circumstances of interest depending on what meta-information is known about the domain.

Comment: @JimMischel: re "but removing is always log(n)"; that is true in general, but not in this case because we have a pre-determined deletion order, given by the insertion list. Think of the elements being stored in a circular buffer. `ALL` information which must be updated on delete is readily available in O(1) because of the pre-determined deletion order. Once Insertion in O(1) is available through hashing, maintenance of the data structure is O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are algorithms with O(1) amortized complexity:

with deque:
[Can min/max of moving window achieve in O(N)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/)

with two stacks: 
[Implement a queue in which push_rear(), pop_front() and get_min() are all constant time operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802038/)

Comment: It's possible to get worst-case O(1) by recalculating the suffix maxima on a schedule. See e.g. [my implementation in C++](http://www.davideisenstat.com/reduq/).

Comment: Nice! The deque implementation is particularly pretty.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Could you explain your data structure in an answer (or comments in your code)? I'm interested but C++ is not my native language.

Comment: @Dan At a high level, each node has a "max" field that stores the max from that node to some node behind it. We continually scan back to front, updating that field. Since the scan takes only one step per push/pop operation, the structure is nodes last updated by the previous scan, followed by nodes last updated by the current scan, followed by nodes never updated. We maintain maxima for (i) the nodes that arrived since the previous scan began and (ii) the nodes that arrived since the current scan began. Unfortunately, the devil is in the details, which I haven't had time to write up yet.

Comment: My library comes with an exhaustive test suite for short sequences of operations.

Comment: @Dan I updated the link with some (hopefully) clear pseudocode and sketched a proof of correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Cases:

1. New >= CurrentMax and First anything: CurrentMax updated to New;
2. New < CurrentMax and First < Current Max: Unchanged;
3. New < CurrentMax and First >= Current Max: Search to determine new CurrentMax;

However:

In order to make the 3rd case performant you need to maintain a (doubly-linked) list of the elements in insertion order, and a tree in size order. Then you simply perform the insertion/deletion in both the list and the tree, and read off the new current max from the tree. This is as efficient going forward as your tree implementation, O(N) to build the insertion order list, and O(N log N) to construct the ranking tree.

The data structure to hold list elements would look something like this:

```
public class Element {
  Element PrevInsertionOrder;
  Element NextInsertionOrder;
  Element RankingTreeParent;
  Element RankingTreeLeftChild;
  Element RankingTreeRightChild;
  int Data;
}
```

Update:

By maintaining a second (doubly linked) list of distinct key values with occurrence counts (instead of the second tree above), O(1) time to perform the MAX determination seems to be possible.

Comment: How is this constant time going forward?  How do you make insertions into the size-ordered list in O(1) time?

Comment: This still doesn't meet the O(1) requirement going forward.  Tree insertions and deletions are O(log(n)) in the average case.

Comment: @torquestomp: Which is why I removed that claim from the post, to state that it will be limited by the efficiency of the tree implementation. (Most likely O(log N) as you state.)

Comment: The expressly stated purpose of the question is to determine whether an algorithm exists that can beat O(log N) runtime for successive operations, so this post adds no value, unless there's a Tree structure out there that somehow guarantees O(1) insertion/deletion time.

Comment: How would a second linked list with occurrence count solve this in O(1)? Without random access, the best you can do with using a linked list for keeping track of the occurrence count is O(n) since you'll have to iterate to find the element being inserted. To make that second linked list useful, it would have to be kept sorted, which wouldn't only not help with the complexity of keeping track of occurrence count, but would cost and additional O(n) for insertion to remain sorted.

Comment: He's not claiming O(1) for insertion, just for determining the new MAX.  O(log(N)) for insertion remains, and is the limiting factor.