# Maximum/Minimum of all subarrays/ Windows of size k (Must Read the Accepted Answer, New Method)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an Array of Size n , that is it have n elements in it. and window size 'W'. you have to find maximum in all subarrays of size 'W'. starting from index 0.

```
Sample Input:
n=10 , W = 3 // n is number of element in array and W is window size.

10 3
1 -2 5 6 0 9 8 -1 2 0

Answer = 5 6 6 9 9 9 8 2
```

What i tried -
  (Self-Balancing BST)

1. Pick first k elements and create a Self-Balancing Binary Search Tree (BST) of size W.
2. Run a loop for i = 0 to n – W

   1. Get the maximum element from the BST, and print it.
   2. Search for arr[i] in the BST and delete it from the BST.
   3. Insert arr[i+W] into the BST.

Time Complexity:

1. Step 1 is `O(WLogW).`
2. Time Complexity of steps 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 is `O(LogW)`. Since Steps of 
   2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 are in a loop that runs `n-W+1 times`, time
   complexity of the complete algorithm is `O(WLogW + (n-W+1)*LogW)`
   which can also be written as `O(nLogW)`.

**My Question is can i improve it ? any suggestion on BST approach or Any other algorithm i haven't heard if ?**

Everywhere i see only Dequeue Method. isn't there any Method ?

Comment: This can be Easily solved by dynamic programming in O(n) ? tried ?

Comment: how ? i have seen method of dequeue. but i didn't get it.

Comment: Deqeue method is Quite Common.  it is in O(n). have you tried it ?

Comment: You said about Dynamic Programming Method ? how to do it using that ? can you explain ?

Comment: Try it once ! else i will tell approach . it is common approach to come up with !

Comment: Can you tell me a way, all i can find is DEQUEUE method !

Comment: What's wrong with the Dequeue method?

Comment: that is hard to understand !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on

Comment: http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html

Comment: yeah that's right ! but please look at solution below, you won't be disappointed i assure. this answer is different from all duplicates on Stackoverflow