# C++: Find the maximum integer in an array of sub-arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, max, sub-array

I'm facing an issue where I want to write an algorithm that can return the max element of each consecutive sub-array of k elements within a larger array, and have these max elements read into their own array, like so:

```
Given int array = {3, 7, 20, 6, 12, 2, 0, 99, 5, 16}, and int k = 4,
--> creates the array {20, 20, 20, 12, 99, 99, 99} 
[because there are 7 consecutive sub-arrays of size 4 within the given array:
{3, 7, 20, 6}, {7, 20, 6, 12}, {20, 6, 12, 2}, ... , {0, 99, 5, 16}
and the max element of these, respectively, is 20, 20, 20, ..., 99 which 
are read into the resulting array.
```

**Now here is my issue:** I know how to implement this in O(n^2) complexity, but want to make it faster such that it can be O(n), or if that's not possible, O(nlog(n)). Does anyone know if there is a faster way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: *consecutive sub-arrays. Sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: I don't think you can make this more efficient in terms of execution complexity unless you have some form of heuristics. If these data structures were trees you could use advanced truncation algorithms such as alpha-beta pruning. So unfortunately i think you can only make it more elegant using recursion and you're stuck with `O(n^2)`

Comment: Don't you mean O(nk) complexity instead of O(n^2)? The naive approach seems to be scanning the k elements in each subarray and selecting the largest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can min/max of moving window achieve in O(N)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the complexity of the naive algorithm is **O(k(n-k+1))** (usually this is approximated to **O(k.n)**), not **O(n^2)**.  That's where, for each consecutive subarray (of **n-k+1** possible), you must perform **k** comparisons.

You can do better than this with some *memoization*, using an additional array of length **k**, which we can call `maximums`.  That array will store the index of the next maximum.

For every iteration through your data set, you examine the first element of `maximums`.  You remove any "expired" indices, and now the first element is your answer for the current iteration.

As you slide a window (size **k**) across your data, you push the current index onto `maximums`, and then prune it as follows: the value at index `maximums[i]` *must* be less than the value at index `maximums[i-1]`.  If it is not, then you continue to bubble the index towards the beginning of `maximums`, one spot at a time until this becomes true.

In reality, it's best to treat the `maximums` array as a ring buffer.  The pruning process will shrink the tail back toward the head, while popping any "expired" maximums (when the window slides past them) will advance the head one step.

It's a little clunky, but here's some working code to illustrate:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int window_size = 4;
    std::vector<int> vals = { 3, 7, 20, 6, 12, 2, 0, 99, 5, 16 };
    std::vector<int> maximums( window_size );
    int mhead = 0, mtail = 0;

    for( int i = 1; i < vals.size(); i ++ )
    {
        // Clean out expired maximum.
        if( maximums[mhead] + window_size <= i )
        {
            int next_mhead = (mhead + 1) % window_size;
            if( mtail == mhead ) mtail = next_mhead;
            mhead = next_mhead;
        }

        if( vals[i] >= vals[ maximums[mtail] ] )
        {
            // Replace and bubble up a new maximum value.
            maximums[mtail] = i;
            while( mhead != mtail && vals[ maximums[mtail] ] >= vals[ maximums[(mtail+window_size-1)%window_size] ] )
            {
                int prev_mtail = (mtail + window_size - 1) % window_size;
                maximums[prev_mtail] = maximums[mtail];
                mtail = prev_mtail;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Add a new non-maximum.
            mtail = (mtail + 1) % window_size;
            maximums[mtail] = i;
        }

        // Output current maximum.
        if( i >= window_size - 1 )
        {
            std::cout << vals[ maximums[mhead] ] << " ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the time complexity...

Best case is **O(n)**, which happens if all your data is sorted (either ascending or descending).

Worst case, I believe, is **O(2n)**.  The only way to require **k** extra operations in one iteration is if you have already had **k** steps of linear complexity (so that the ring buffer is full).  And in such a case, the ring buffer will be empty for the next step.  Since we can fill and empty the ring buffer only **n/k** times, those occasional **k** operations come out at **k.n/k**, or just **n**.

You ought to be able to show that even constant partial emptying of the ring buffer will result in the same complexity.

And finally, we can wrap up and call the whole thing **O(n)**, since any constant factor becomes insignificant for large **n**.  It actually came out better than I expected. =)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that, like many algorithms, the naive approach may be more suitable for small values of **k**, but as **k** is made larger, the benefits of the linear time algorithm begin to show.