# calculating max(min(A[i .. i+d])) in O(n) time O(n) memory

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, max, min

I had an algorithm problem asking to get  `max(min(A[i .. i+d]))` in `O (n)` time.
General Solution:

```
int max = 0;
for( i = 0; i< n-d; i++){
  int min = MX;
  for( j = i; j < i + d; j++)
     if(min > A[j])
       min = A[j];
  if(max < min)
     max = min;
}
printf("%d\n", max);
```

But it will take O(n x d) not O(n)

Better Solution: using  [Range_minimum_query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query)

```
int max = 0;
for( i = 0; i< n-d; i++){
  int min = RMQ( i , i + d);
  if(max < min)
     max = min;
}
printf("%d\n", max);
```

It will take `O(log(d) * n)` as RMQ's average time is `log(d)`

I thought this problem in my head about 15 days, but not renovation yet.
Could anyone solve this problem efficiently?

i/o data: `1<n<10^7 1<d<n`

```
input : n = 10, d = 3, A[i] > 0
1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
result : 8 //= max(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe an input/output example? I don't fully understand the task

Comment: This is known as the "range minimum query" problem.

Comment: Look at [Range_minimum_query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query).

Comment: @Jarod42 Does it support O(n+d)? I think it will take o((log d) * n)

Comment: hmm I don't think this is O(n*d)  but rather O((n-d)*d)

Comment: Note that the shown algorithm suppose `d` dynamic too.

Comment: For fixed sized ranges there is this research paper. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.4547

Comment: Thanks but d is dynamic  1< d < n

Comment: RMQ is for random access, for sequentual access there is better method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on/12195098#12195098

Comment: There's [this algorithm](https://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html) with amortized O(n) running time. Whatever you do, make sure to cite your sources when you turn in the assignment, so you aren't guilty of academic dishonesty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Range minimum query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) philosophy (which is good for random access), I would use a [Double-ended queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) (which is good for sequential access), which offers a average complexity of O(1) for all operations<sup>*</sup>.

*<sub>except insertion/deletion)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you provide full answer?