# How to optimize getting maximum values in array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14, c++17

There is a function which is getting maximum values of each `period`-length interval in array.

```
void f(const std::vector<double> &v, std::vector<double> &vv, size_t period)
{
    vv.resize(v.size());

    for (size_t i = period; i <= v.size(); ++i) {
        vv[i - 1] = *std::max_element(v.begin() + i - period, v.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

How can I optimize this function by performance?

Comment: Why multiple C++ standards tagged? Is the code required to conform to all of them or something?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I mean c++11-17 is allowed for my project.

Comment: As a naive solution you can try to keep sorted multiset and update it while moving to the next period. This should give you O(N*logN) performance for adding / removing elements and O(1) to get max element

Comment: See range maximum query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on/12195098#12195098

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the preceding calculated max value coincide with the first value of the preceding range: if not, the new max become the `std::max` between the old max and the last position of the new interval.

Something as (caution: code not tested)

```
void f(const std::vector<double> &v, std::vector<double> &vv, size_t period)
{
    vv.resize(v.size());

    bool oldMaxFirst = false;

    for (size_t i = period; i <= v.size(); ++i) {
        if ( oldMaxFirst )
           vv[i - 1] = std::max(vv[i - 2], v[i - 1]);
        else
           vv[i - 1] = *std::max_element(v.begin() + i - period, v.begin() + i);

        oldMaxFirst = vv[i - 1] == v[i - period];
    }
}
```

or also (but the code become a little obfuscated)

```
void f(const std::vector<double> &v, std::vector<double> &vv, size_t period)
{
    vv.resize(v.size());

    bool oldMaxFirst = false;

    for (size_t i = period; i <= v.size(); ++i) {
        oldMaxFirst = v[i - period] == (vv[i - 1] = (oldMaxFirst
            ? std::max(vv[i - 2], v[i - 1])
            : *std::max_element(v.begin() + i - period, v.begin() + i) );      }
}
```

Comment: Still O(n^2) asymptotic complexity. Will be faster or slower depeding on how often the `max()` path is taken.