# Tracking maximum of data stream over last n values without storing all n values

Tags: algorithm

Given a stream of real numbers, it is simple to keep track of the maximum value across the entire history of the stream.

However, I am running into difficulty calculating the maximum of the last `n` numbers in the stream. So for the stream `{5, 7, 3, 6, 2, 0, 1}`, with `n = 3`, the maximum at each index would be `{5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 2}`

Specifically, while it would be simple to create a list of the past `n` values and calculate the maximum of that list as needed, I can not envision a means of doing so without storing such a possibly large list. Is a more efficient implementation possible?

Comment: [Yes, it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190184/can-min-max-of-moving-window-achieve-in-on/12195098#12195098)

Comment: That will work. @MBo since you are the author of the original answer, if you answer again here, perhaps with a link to the original and a brief synopsis, I can mark it as accepted.